# TensorBoard not working

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I'm able to use TensorFlow just fine. But I can't yet use TensorBoard at all. I'm following the instructions on tensorflow.org's [Visualizing Learning page](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html).

When I run

```
tensorboard --logdir=/tmp/mnist_logs --debug
```

I get the following

```
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard is in debug mode.
INFO:tensorflow:Starting TensorBoard in directory /private/tmp/mnist_logs
INFO:tensorflow:TensorBoard path_to_run is: {'/tmp/mnist_logs': None}
INFO:tensorflow:Adding events from directory /tmp/mnist_logs
INFO:tensorflow:Constructing EventAccumulator for /tmp/mnist_logs
DEBUG:tensorflow:Opening a record reader pointing at /tmp/mnist_logs/events.out.tfevents.1457792617.Rafaels-MacBook-Air
WARNING:tensorflow:IOError [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG' on path /usr/local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/tensorboard/TAG
WARNING:tensorflow:Unable to read TensorBoard tag
Starting TensorBoard  on port 6006
(You can navigate to http://0.0.0.0:6006)
DEBUG:tensorflow:No more events in /tmp/mnist_logs/events.out.tfevents.1457792617.Rafaels-MacBook-Air
INFO:tensorflow:No more files in /tmp/mnist_logs
DEBUG:tensorflow:No more events in /tmp/mnist_logs/events.out.tfevents.1457792617.Rafaels-MacBook-Air
INFO:tensorflow:No more files in /tmp/mnist_logs
INFO:tensorflow:Multiplexer done loading. Load took 0.9 secs
```

If I nagivate to `http://0.0.0.0:6006`, I see a blank white page.

[Stack: OSX, Google Chrome, Python 3, TensorFlow installed via pip]

Comment: Which web browser and operating system are you using?

Comment: Added. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I get "Unable to read TensorBoard tag" every time, but it still works, I think your problem is likely not related to that message

Comment: Ok, I'll change the title of my question.

Comment: Looks like this is related to https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/1421, which is a really frustrating heisenbug. I haven't been able to repro it myself, although several other people have reported it. if you have a consistent repro that will make it a lot easier to track down.

Comment: Darn heisenbugs, I reran tensor board after a few days and it worked! What's the recommended way to deal with this on SO?

Comment: When I follow the link given in terminal it also gives directs me to a blank page. But if I copy and paste the link into my browser it works fine. Dont know what is happening there... [Stack: OSX, Google Chrome, Python 3, TensorFlow installed via pip] Ps. I would/should have commented on, not answered, this question. But my reputation is too low.

Answer (score 27):

Try navigating to [localhost:6006](http://localhost:6006/) instead (equivalent to http://127.0.0.1:6006/).

It works fine for me while http://0.0.0.0:6006 yields no result.

Comment: Worked for me, tensorboard was asking me to go to my "Computer name",
i.e. http://<Computer Name>:6006 but it didn't work
while http://localhost:6006 works

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Ivanov. I had the same problem. I changed to localhost:6006 and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with TensorBoard 1.4 (no errors on start but black page in browser). In my case it helped to set the host explicitly to 127.0.0.1 with --host