# TensorBoard doesn't load properly

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

Tensorboard doesn't seem to load properly when installed on my machine. I'm using Python 3.7 and Tensorboard 1.13.1 in a virtual environment. I'm running a very simple sample script:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3.0)
b = tf.constant(4.0)
c = a+b

sess = tf.Session()

print(sess.run(c))

writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('.')
writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
writer.flush()

sess.close()

tf.reset_default_graph()
```

When I run tensorboard within the virtual environment, I receive

```
TensorBoard 1.13.1 at http://S13:6006 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Now, when I open the page on Firefox, I get the following result:
[Firefox Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49mfT.png)

On a fresh installation of chromium, I get:
[Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PyUjU.png)

It never finishes loading.

I'm running Fedora 25.01. I've tried searching the web for this error, but could not find anything. Would appreciate any kind of help.

PS: I managed to get tensorflow+board to run on a fedora machine with a very similar setup. There, tensorboard works without any issues.

EDIT: Tensorboard doesn't display any errors or warnings in the console.

Comment: I was having a very similar problem. Try loading "localhost:6006" instead of what you were given. Worked for me. Check out this Q/A where I found this possible solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35961348/tensorboard-not-working

Answer (score 0):

I change your code into this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(3.0, name='a')
b = tf.constant(4.0, name='b')
c = tf.add(a, b, name='add_operation')


writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('./dummy')
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(c)
    writer.add_graph(tf.get_default_graph())
```

Then in terminal in the SAME working directory, type: `tensorboard --logdir='./dummy/' --port 6006`. Please try and tell me if it works